# Segment distance between two 3D points divided by xy plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Two points in space, first is above xy plane, the other is below. The distance is basic hypotenuse. But how to calculate the length of the segment below xy plane?

(in 2D, I figured it is simply segmentbelow =  distance * y2/(y2-y1) which is very simple.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the following notations:

- $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ with $z_1 \geq 0$, i.e., above $xy$ plane,
- $P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ is with $z_2 \leq 0$, i.e., below $xy$ plane, and
- $I$ be the intersection point of line segment $P_1P_2$ with plane $xy$.

The length $L$ of line segment $P_1P_2$ is given by  $L=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}.$

In order to obtain the length $IM_2$, we must multiply $L$ by a "reducing factor" equal to the ratio

$$\tag{1}\frac{IM_2}{M_1M_2}=\frac{-z_2}{z_1-z_2}$$

(we have to write $-z_2$ for working with positive quantities).

Remarks about formula (1):

1) The fact that only coordinate $z$ is used is a consequence of Thales property.

2) It is the very same formula you have found in the 2D case.